# Кроссплатформенность python, c++

Tags: python, c++

Если я соберу с .py файл .exe - он будет работать на всех версиях OS Windows?

Если я напишу программу на крестах, аналогичный вопрос - она будет работать везде?

И какой компилятор выбрать для С++ для создания GUI на windows?

Мне нужна полная 100%-я кроссплатформенность. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: >> И какой компилятор выбрать для С++ для создания GUI на windows?

Возможно вам стоит сначала стоит прочитать что такое компилятор и что такое фреймворк.

>> 100%-я кроссплатформенность

это вы про разные версии виндоус говорите? или вам действительно нужно что бы это работало и в мак ос и линуксах? В любом случае я советую вам взятся за QT. Это кроссплатформенный фреймворк

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Если вам не нужна поддержка того, что устарело уже не только морально, но и физически(например Win95/98), то советую даже не думать над этим вопросом, ибо почти все виндузятники сидят на XP и старше.

3) А какие компиляторы под Windows сейчас используются?

**GCC**(или MinGW для 90% юзеров) и **MSVC++**, третьего, для большинства, не дано.

А выбор компилятора зависит от вашего проекта. Если это собственные обёртки вокруг WinAPI, то разницы в создании GUI вы не заметите. Если же это какой-либо фреймворк, то, как правило, надо выбирать MSVC.

Мини комментарии по основным(ИМХО) фреймворкам:

1. MFC -- no comments
2. Qt -- он с лёгкостью устанавливается
       в студию, за пару кликов. Советую
       VC.
3. [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) -- тут уже сами
       разработчики советую компилировать в
       VC, т.к. в MinGW бинарники будут
       ОЧЕНЬ большие.

Обобщу: VC почти для всего будет оптимален.

Answer (score 4):

Хочу добавить, что если преследуется цель обеспечения кроссплатформенности, то **просто выбрать Qt в качестве GUI framework будет недостаточно**. На основе своего опыта могу сказать, что если вы разрабатываете на Windows (что, на мой взгляд, гораздо удобнее), то проект надо как минимум собирать еще и под Linux, а еще лучше - собирать и выполнять (если есть юнит-тесты то обязательно их проверять).

Причин для этого достаточно: разность в сигнатурах некоторых функций, а порой и в отсутствии их аналогов под Win или Linux; разный размер типов wchar_t (2 байта в Win и 4 - в Linux);  и пр. Без параллельной сборки и тестирования на всех главных платформах о 100% кроссплатформенности можете забыть.

Кроме того, сборка под x64 имеет ряд существенных отличий от х86, а ведь это тоже часть свойства кросссплатформенности. Об этом можно (и нужно) почитать курс [Андрея Карпова](http://www.viva64.com/ru/l/).